# Is it possible to keep tomb stones after tables compaction?

Tags: cassandra, soft-delete

I understand that entries get marked with tombstones when a deletion in requested in C*. This way, a soft deletion is performed and it is made effective [during compaction](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/tuning#tuning-compaction):

> In addition to consolidating SSTables, the compaction process merges
>   keys, combines columns, **discards tombstones**, and creates a new index
>   in the merged SSTable.

Is it possible to avoid tombstones discard in order to keep them stored for ever? I know that would be against efficiency. I just wonder if it is possible.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @jny I'd like to experiment whether it is possible to perform a logic deletion without adding a `deleted` column to the ColumnFamily. It is just some personal research but I'd appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a higher `gc_grace_seconds` value in your table properties to increase the time until tombstones will be effectively deleted.

Comment: Assuming `gc_grace_seconds` is an unsigned integer I could set it to 136 years. Do you know what is the upper limit for this setting?

Comment: No idea. Its also not making a lot of sense to use tombstones that would never expire. Just use a regular update instead for flagging a row as "soft deleted".